# Django - UpdateView - Empty select field?

Tags: python, django

I have an Updateview :

```
class Cotisations_des_adherentsUpdate(UpdateView):
    model                = Cotisations_des_adherents
    form_class           = UpdateCotisations_des_adherentsForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update'
```

And a model( extract here) :

```
class Cotisations_des_adherents (models.Model):
    n_reglement                  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cotisation_acquittee         = models.FloatField(    blank=True  ,     null=True, choices=settings.CHOICE_OUI_NON)
    frais_de_dossier_acquittes   = models.FloatField(    blank=True  ,     null=True, choices=settings.CHOICE_OUI_NON)
    a_jour                       = models.FloatField(    blank=True  ,     null=True, choices=settings.CHOICE_UN_ZERO)
```

the settings value are :

```
CHOICE_OUI_NON          = [ (1  , "1-oui"     ),
                            (0  , "0-non"     )]
CHOICE_SEXE             = [ (1, "1-Homme"   ),
                            (2, "2-Femme"   ),]
```

And the form_class inherite from a personnal class:

```
class UpdateCotisations_des_adherentsForm(Cotisations_des_adherentsForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateCotisations_des_adherentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Call to ModelForm constructor
```

the super class is (extract here):

```
class Cotisations_des_adherentsForm(ModelForm):
    error_css_class     = 'error'
    required_css_class  = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model   = Cotisations_des_adherents
        fields = [   "n_reglement",
                     "cotisation_acquittee",
                     "a_jour",
                    ]           
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cotisations_des_adherentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My issue is that on the upadte view I don't see the last saved value of the user :

```
cotisation_acquittee         
frais_de_dossier_acquittes   
a_jour
```

gives me an empty select html :
[image]

I understand from [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) that there is something sepecific about the CHOICES option :

> If the model field has choices set, then the form field’s widget will
>   be set to Select, with choices coming from the model field’s choices.
>   The choices will normally include the blank choice which is selected
>   by default. If the field is required, this forces the user to make a
>   selection. The blank choice will not be included if the model field
>   has blank=False and an explicit default value (the default value will
>   be initially selected instead).

(I verified, there are information saved in the db :

```
|2.0|0.0|1.0
```

)

**How can I make the last value saved in the database appearing in the select box in the updating html form ?**

Comment: choices are constant, if you want to show values other than already present in the choices then you need to dynamically load the value.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean : I want to show in the form the last choice the user saved (which is one of the value I fixed in the choices)

Comment: What's the point of that subclass? It doesn't add anything at all to the parent class. (And there's definitely no point in defining `__init__` methods that only call the parent ones.)

Comment: And why are you using float fields here? The choice of oui or non should be a boolean field.

Comment: @romainjouin ah..got you. that means data is not save correctly. when used selected an option from dropdown and saved. Then when next time dropdown is populated it should show the last saved option if model field is correctly save earlier.

Comment: @Roseman : I use a mother-class to set the lenght and width of the html widgets. But i didn't show the code here not to confuse the reader

Comment: @Rosemann : Agreed, integer would be enough, but I am reloading old files with floats - so to be compatible I stay with integers.

Comment: @MA : strange, to me the db seems to have saved the value. But the strange things is that there are stuff in the db : even the old value are not loaded !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of floats here is central to your problem. Although `1` and `1.0` are numerically equivalent, they are not the same value and therefore the form does not recognise the `1.0` stored in the database as being one of the possible choices in the form.

You could probably fix this by using `1.0` and `0.0` as the values in your CHOICES tuples, but the proper way is to use the correct data type in the first place, which is Boolean.